# What is the best way to avoid many if statements?

Tags: javascript

What is the best and ellegant way for refactoring the following `if` statements?

```
if (!this.props.isRequired) {
  return false
}
if (items.length < 1) {
  return false
}
if (items.length === 1) {
  return true
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you might group them together using &&, || or you can use `switch` instead; you might want to exclude some of them into separate functions and call them. It really depends. Don't see why would you change them in your particular case.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to?  IMO this is clean and readable.

Comment: You can try to group the similar return value and keep in single if statement with || conditions.

Comment: Assign a boolean variable to each condition, and solve a Karnaugh map of all the variables to achieve the minimal required expression for your logic. (bit of an overkill though... ;) )

Comment: @AlessioCantarella do you mean that `1 < 1` evaluates to `true` ?

Comment: What is IMO? Can someone please tell me the full form?

Comment: @Bhawan "in my opinion".  You'll sometimes see IMHO - "in my honest/humble opinion".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `||` to alternate between all conditions that will return the same value:

```
if (!this.props.isRequired || items.length < 1) {
  return false
}
if (items.length === 1) {
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should handle the case where `items.length` is > 1, too:

```
return (this.props.isRequired && items.length === 1);
```

You can omit the `if` and just return the boolean true/false value directly.

Comment: This changes the logic of the condition.

Comment: We also don't know if there's further logic beyond the posted code that handles the case of `length > 1` too.  If there isn't, the OP code would be returning `undefined`, which would be odd.

Comment: Yes true. Unfortunately the code snippet in the question does not show what is supposed to happen when none of the `if`s are true.

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (!this.props.isRequired || items.length < 1) {
    return false
 }
 else if (items.length === 1) {
     return true
  }
```

Comment: `else` is superfluous. If the first part is `true`, the second won't be evaluated because of the `return`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
return !this.props.isRequired ? false : (items.length === 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ternary

```
this.props.isRequired || items.length < 1 ? return false: null;
items.length === 1 ? return true: null;
```

Comment: ick... I'd rather have 3 individiual `if` statements!

Comment: Imagine refactoring 20 `if` statements into ternary

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you write business logic !!!

Now in above code you can merge first two if statements in one as both returns same value.

```
    if (!this.props.isRequired  || items.length < 1) {
        return false
    }

    if (items.length === 1) {
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were to come across these exact lines during refactoring (or review), I'd immediately look for the next/last return statement, as these lines appear to indicate the function has multiple output types.

Having different return types is something I try to avoid in general.

As for the reduction in if statements; my first step would be to make the if statements conclusive, which seems to come down to answering the question whether `items.length` would be valid if it's greater than `1`.

If so, you can turn it into a single statement.

```js
return this.props.isRequired && items.length >= 1;
```

If not, you can use the non-conclusive part (`> 1`) condition (or the inverse, to make it more concise)

```js
if (items.length <= 1) {
  return this.props.isRequired && items.length === 1;
}
//  the alternative flow (not in your example)
```